# Can I use swipe to delete as swipe to do some other action using titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, sdk

In my iOS app I'd like to implement swipe to "add this item to a watchlist" sort of action.

Using titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath it's possible to change "Delete" to some other title.

I'm wondering if Apple would allow such handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before, and its OK for the App Store.

You may simply add an **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** to every cell in the UITableView Delegate: **cellForRowAtIndex**, and set the direction property as left/right. Then add your own button subview to the cell, and just pop it out when a swipe gesture is being detected.

BTW, Apple is using this trick in the 'iPod' app on iOS 5.0 to show the music detail pop-up view ;-)